# Unexpected 10 Second Delay on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is the script that I run on a game, Tribal Wars - I only mention the game in case there's something going on with the events, and perhaps event listening, that is causing this. Mostly consistent unexpected delay of around 10 seconds give or take a second and a half and a few hundred ms or so.

```
javascript: function attak() {

    var MONTH = prompt('MONTH:');
    var DAY = prompt('DAY:');
    var HOUR = prompt('HOUR?:');
    var MINUTES = prompt('MINUTES?:');
    var SECONDS = prompt('SECONDS?:');
    var MIL = prompt('MIL?:');
    var now = new Date();
    var time = new Date(now.getFullYear(), MONTH - 1, DAY, HOUR, MINUTES, SECONDS, MIL);
    var millisTill = time - now;
    var month = MONTH.toString();
    var day = DAY.toString();
    var hour = HOUR.toString();
    var minutes = MINUTES.toString();
    var seconds = SECONDS.toString();
    var mil = MIL.toString();
    var timek = 'attack start [' + month + ' / ' + day + ' - ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + mil + ']';
    var newtext = document.createTextNode(timek);
    var par = document.getElementById("content_value");
    par.appendChild(newtext);

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms[0].submit.click();
    }, millisTill);
}
attak();
```

When ran, you are prompted for the month, day, hour, minute, second, ms of your local time for when the time the script is supposed to execute (I did not write this myself, and I realize it's messy).

Thus it creates the event (I am a bit of a noob, hope I'm explaining this properly) then waits (listens?) until the launch time and sends. It executes at the proper time, but delays give or take 10 seconds before it executes the attak() function and sends the attack/support command button.

What precisely is causing this unexpected delay?

Thank you very much. This will be my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You do know that `setTimeout` is a timeout of a least x milliseconds. Can last to the end of time if it chooses to do so.

Comment: Are you sure the ~10s delay is not due to the time it takes for the server to execute the request after you simulate the click on the submit button ? 
How did you measure this 10s delay ?  
If you do a ```console.log(new Date())``` before the ```setTimeout``` and one inside the inner function. What do you get ? 

@EdHeal setTimeout is not completely reliable but I'd be surprised to see differences of ~10s with what you are asking to the method

Comment: Stranger things have happened - the pope being a horse - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_%28horse%29

Comment: @Ed Heal
I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. It is calculating the timeout (my bad posting this as setInterval) using current date, then changing using the ms from the prompt time strings... 

Are you meaning that setTimeout isn't precise at all?

Also, the usual delay between command send and server getting it, is usually around 220 ms to 350 ms depending how my internet is that day. Never 10 or more seconds. Regardless of how the command is sent.

Comment: @maximede I've just now done some more tests, and instead of 10 seconds, it's accurately doing about 15 seconds instead. The kicker though is that I have to send 2-3 commands using the same launch time, and the first one has a more random time to send. 140545, 150366, 150466 were the total ms delay from the time it was supposed to send on last test. Will add some consolelogs now

Comment: Would it be better to use setImmediate in place of setTimeout, in cases where precise ms execution is necessary? From what I've just read basically only IE supports this right now though? 

Is there any other ways to make this work better other than just subtracting 14000 ms from the time to send and have it execute that much earlier? 

I also read this may have to do with total items processed causing the delay. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/11/timed-array-processing-in-javascript/
" First, the size of the delay is too long for large arrays. ....  takes at least 10,000 more ms..."

Comment: You are not processing any items in your inner function, just simulating a click on a button. Substracting 14000ms might be a workaround if the problem is coming from the fact that the request takes a long time to be executed. But I'd do that first to confirm : "How did you measure this 10s delay ? If you do a console.log(new Date()) before the setTimeout and one inside the inner function. What do you get ?"